# How to search for a particular record in the table?

Tags: python

I am making a hospital management system and I want to write a code for searching a particular record specified by the user.

This is the project code:

```
import mysql.connector as sqltor
from datetime import datetime
conn= sqltor.connect(host='localhost', user='root', password='root',database='hosp_management')
cur=conn.cursor()
#print(conn) 
#if (conn):
        #print('successfully connected')
#else:
       #print('connection not successful')
#cur=conn.cursor()

#sql="create table patient(PMR_NO varchar(10), NAME varchar(200), AGE int, SEX char(1), ADDRESS varchar(25), PHONE_NO int(15), EMAIL_ID VARCHAR(80), SPONSOR varchar(150),INSURANCE_ID int(10), primary key(PMR_NO))"
#cur.execute(sql)
#print('table created successfully')

#admin= 'create table admin(USERNAME varchar(100), PASSWORD varchar(10))'
#cur.execute(admin)
#print('table created successfully')

#doctor='create table doctor(ID_NO varchar(10) not null, NAME varchar(120) not null, SPE varchar(120) not null, LOC varchar(120) not null, LOC2 varchar(120) not null, primary key(ID_NO, LOC, LOC2))'
#cur.execute(doctor)
#conn.commit()
#print('TABLE CREATED SUCCESSFULLY')

#appt='create table appointment(PMR_NO varchar(10) not null, NAME varchar(150) not null, EMAIL_ID varchar(100), PHONE_NO int(12) not null, DEPT varchar(100) not null, DOCTOR varchar(150) not null, ID_NO varchar(10) not null, DATE date, TIME time, SPONSOR varchar(150), INSURANCE_ID int(10), primary key(PMR_NO))'
#cur.execute(appt)
#conn.commit()
#print('table created')

#doctor_login='create table doctor_login_details(USERNAME varchar(100),  PASSWORD varchar(10))'
#cur.execute(doctor_login)
#print('table created successfully')


def admin_menu():
    while(True):
        info=int(input('''
1. Registration
2. Sign in
0. Exit
ENTER YOUR CHOICE: '''))
        
        #REGISTRATION
        if info==1:
                    print('')
                    USERNAME= input('USERNAME:')
                    PASSWORD= input('PASSWORD:')
                    cur.execute('select username, password from ADMIN')
                    reg=cur.fetchall()
                    for i in reg:
                        if (USERNAME in i):
                            index=reg.index(i)
                            if (USERNAME==reg[index][0] and PASSWORD==reg[index][1]):
                                print('')
                                print('ALREADY REGISTERED')
                                print('PLEASE LOGIN WITH THE ENTERED CREDENTIALS')
                                conn.commit()
                                admin_menu()
                        else:
                                u_name="insert into admin(USERNAME, PASSWORD) values (%s,%s)"
                                clm= USERNAME,PASSWORD
                                cur.execute(u_name, clm)
                                print('REGISTRATION SUCCESSFUL')
                                conn.commit()
                                admin_det()
        if info==2:
                #LOGIN
                print('')
                u_name2= input('USERNAME:')
                pw= input('PASSWORD:')
                cur.execute("select username , password from ADMIN")
                l1 = cur.fetchall()
                #SUCCESSFUL LOGIN ATTEMPT
                for i in l1:
                        if(u_name2 in i):
                            index_ = l1.index(i)
                            if(u_name2 == l1[index_][0] and pw== l1[index_][1]):
                                print('')
                                print("LOGIN SUCCESSFUL")
                                conn.commit()
                                admin_det()

                #UNSUCESSFUL LOGIN ATTEMPT
                else:
                    
                    print("INVALID USERNAME OR PASSWORD ")
                    print('PLEASE LOGIN AGAIN OR REGISTER YOUR ACCOUNT')
                    conn.commit()
                    admin_menu()   

        #RETURN TO MAIN MENU        
        if info==0:
            main()


def admin_det():
    list_ = int(input("""
             ADMIN MENU 
                            
1. Add details
2. Update details
3. Retrieve details
4. Delete details
5. Search details
6. Book appointment
0. RETURN TO MAIN MENU
ENTER YOUR CHOICE: """))
    
    #TO CREATE DETAILS
    if list_==1:
            choice= int(input("""
        CREATE DETAILS
                              
1. Patient
2. Doctor
0. Exit
ENTER CHOICE: """  ))
            
            #CREATE
            if choice==1:
                print('')
                PMR_NO= input('Patient Medical Record Number:')
                NAME= input('Name:')
                AGE= int(input('Age:'))
                SEX=input('Sex:')
                ADDRESS= input('Address:')
                PHONE_NO= int(input('Phone number:'))
                EMAIL_ID=input('Email ID:')
                SPONSOR= input('Sponsor:')
                INSURANCE_ID= int(input('Insurance ID:'))
                rec= "insert into patient(PMR_NO, NAME, AGE, SEX,ADDRESS,PHONE_NO, EMAIL_ID, SPONSOR, INSURANCE_ID) values(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s,%s,%s)"
                column= PMR_NO, NAME, AGE, SEX, ADDRESS, PHONE_NO, EMAIL_ID, SPONSOR,INSURANCE_ID
                cur.execute(rec, column)
                print('')
                print("""PATIENT DETAILS CREATED SUCCESSFULLY""")
                print('')
                conn.commit()
                admin_det()

            #CREATING DOCTOR DETAILS
            elif choice==2:
                print('')
                ID_NO=input('Id_number:')
                NAME= input('Name:')
                SPE=input('Speciality:')
                LOC=input('Primary practice location:')
                LOC2=input('Secondary practice location:')
                rec2="insert into doctor(ID_NO, NAME, SPE, LOC, LOC2) values(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
                column2= ID_NO, NAME, SPE, LOC, LOC2
                cur.execute(rec2, column2)
                print('')
                print("""DOCTOR DETAILS ADDED SUCCESSFULLY""")
                print('')
                conn.commit()
                admin_det()

            #RETURN TO MAIN MENU
            elif choice==0:
                 main()
    #UPDATE 
    elif list_==2:
            edit=int(input("""
        UPDATE DETAILS:
                           
1. Update patient details
2. Update doctor details
0. Exit
ENTER CHOICE: """))
            
            #UPDATE PATIENT DETAILS
            if edit==1:
                    def update_details_patient():
                        print('')
                        PMR_NO=int(input('PMR_NO:'))
                        NAME= input('Name:')
                        AGE= int(input('Age:'))
                        SEX=input('Sex:')
                        ADDRESS= input('Address:')
                        PHONE_NO= int(input('Phone number:'))
                        EMAIL_ID=input('Email ID:')
                        SPONSOR= input('Sponsor:')
                        INSURANCE_ID= int(input('Insurance ID:'))
                        cur.execute("update patient set NAME= '{}', AGE= {}, SEX= '{}',  ADDRESS='{}', PHONE_NO= {},  EMAIL_ID='{}',SPONSOR= '{}', INSURANCE_ID= {} where PMR_NO= {}".format(NAME,AGE,SEX,ADDRESS,PHONE_NO,SPONSOR,INSURANCE_ID,PMR_NO))
                        conn.commit()
                        conn.close()
                        print('')
                        print('PATIENT DETAILS UPDATED SUCCESSFULLY')
                        print('')
                        admin_menu()
                    update_details_patient()

            #UPDATE DOCTOR DETAILS
            elif edit==2:
                    def update_details_doctor():
                      print('')
                      ID_NO=int(input('ID_NO'))
                      NAME=input('NAME:')
                      SPE=input('SPECIALIZATION:')
                      LOC=input('PRIMARY PRACTICE LOCATION:')
                      LOC2=input('SECONDARY PRACTICE LOCATION:')
                      cur.execute("update doctor set NAME='{}', SPE='{}', LOC='{}', LOC2='{}' where ID_NO={}".format(NAME,SPE,LOC,LOC2,ID_NO))
                      conn.commit()
                      conn.close()
                      print('')
                      print('DOCTOR DETAILS UPDATED SUCCESSFULLY')
                      print('')
                      admin_menu()
                    update_details_doctor()

            #RETURN TO MAIN MENU
            elif edit==0:
                 main()

    #RETRIEVE
    elif list_==3:
        search=int(input("""
        Display the details of:
1. Patient
2. Doctor
0. Exit
ENTER CHOICE:"""))
        #RETRIVE PATIENT DETAILS
        if search==1:
                def retreive_details_patient():
                        sql_select_Query = "select * from patient"
                        cur.execute(sql_select_Query)
                        records = cur.fetchall()
                        print("Total number of rows in table: ", cur.rowcount)
                        for row in records:
                            print('Patient medical record number=',  row[0])
                            print('Name=', row[1])
                            print('Age=', row[2])
                            print('Sex=', row[3])
                            print('Address=', row[4])
                            print('Phone number=', row[5])
                            print('Email ID',row[6])
                            print('Sponsor=', row[7])
                            print('Insurance ID=', row[8])
                            print('')
                retreive_details_patient()
                admin_det()

        #RETREIVE DOCTOR DETAILS
        elif search==2:
                def retreive_details_doctor():
                    print('\n')
                    select='select*from doctor'
                    cur.execute(select)
                    records=cur.fetchall()
                    print("Total number of rows in table: ", cur.rowcount)
                    for row in records:
                        print('ID number', row[0])
                        print('Name=', row[1])
                        print('Specialization=', row[2])
                        print('Primary practice location=', row[3])
                        print('Secondary practice location=', row[4])
                        print('')   
                retreive_details_doctor()
                admin_det()
                
        #RETURN TO MAIN MENU
        elif search==0:
             main()

    elif list_==4:
         details=int(input("""
            Delete the details of:
1. Patient
2. Doctor
0. Exit
ENTER YOUR CHOICE: """))
         if details==1:
              def delete_patient_details():
                   print('\n')
                   PMR_NO=int(input('Enter PMR number to be deleted:'))
                   select="delete from patient where PMR_NO=%s"
                   cur.execute(select,(PMR_NO,))
                   conn.commit()
                   conn.close()
                   print('')
                   print('PATIENT RECORD DELETED SUCCESSFULLY')
                   print('')
                   admin_det()
              delete_patient_details()

         elif details==2:
              def delete_doctor_details():
                   print('')
                   ID_NO=int(input('Enter doctor\'s ID number to be deleted:'))
                   select1="delete from doctor where ID_NO=%s"
                   cur.execute(select1,(ID_NO,))
                   conn.commit()
                   conn.close()
                   print('')
                   print('DOCTOR RECORD DELETED SUCCESSFULLY')
                   print('')
                   admin_det()
              delete_doctor_details()

         elif details==0:
          main()

    elif list==5:
         search=int(input("""
        Search details
1. Patient
2. Doctor
0. EXIT 
ENTER YOUR CHOICE:"""))
         if search==1:
            def search_patient_details():
                PMR_NO=input('PMR_NO:')
                sql_query="selet * from patient where PMR_NO='%{}%'".format(PMR_NO)
                cur.execute(sql_query)
                row=cur.fetchone()
                print(row)   
                conn.commit()
                conn.close()
                admin_det()
            search_patient_details()
def main():
    while True:
        print('                          CITY HOSPITAL')
        print('                     Healthcare at its finest')
        print('')
        print('1. Admin')
        print('2. Doctor')
        print('3. Patient')
        print('0. Exit')
        choice=int(input('enter choice:'))
        if choice==1:
            admin_menu()
        elif choice==2:
            doctor_menu()
        elif choice==3:
            patient_menu()
        elif choice==0:
            break
        else:
            print('')
            print('INVALID OPTION')
            print('PLEASE ENTER THE APPROPRIATE CHOICE')
            print('')
if __name__=="__main__":
    main()

cur.close()
conn.close()
```

However, when i run this code, it redirects me to the admin_menu(). How do I solve this problem. Is the written code for searching a particular record right?
Thanks a lot for your help!
CHEERS!

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67311590/5320906) will help.

Comment: It depends what choice you select.